# C# Populate Textboxes from ListView to new Form

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I have data from my database populating a list view on Form[1].

**Currently** double clicking a row then populates some text boxes underneath the list view.

**However**, i want to accomplish the same thing - but i want the double click to lead to Form[2] and populate form 2 instead. Now, i'm trying to accomplish this but - in my code to generate the method to open the new form with values im getting errors:

```
    private void openForm2Edit(int selID)
    {
        try
        {
            var somevar = new frmForm2(1, selID, this);
            somevar.Show();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error opening value!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

I believe the error is on `frmForm2` and `Form2.Show()`

`> My Error: type/namespace name cannot be found`

and I'm most certain my Form[2] does indeed exist? What could be the problem here?

Comment: It should be `somevar.Show()` not  `Form2.Show();`.

Comment: @HariPrasad yes, but that still leaves the issue with "new frmForm2"

Comment: try this `var somevar = new Form2(1, selID, this); somevar.Show();` a

Comment: Is frmForm2 declared in the same namespace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `frmForm2` is not a class to create an instance.(could be a reference to `Form2`(Just a guess))

Assuming `Form2` has a constructor that takes 3 arguments, you want this.

```
var somevar = new Form2(1, selID, this); 
somevar.Show();
```